# Using Xamarin.Auth with Keycloak

Tags: xamarin.forms, keycloak, xamarin.auth

Does anyone have an example of how to configure Xamarin.Auth (using Forms) to authenticate against Keycloak using OpenID/OAuth2?

Comment: R u searching for this http://www.joesauve.com/using-xamarin-auth-with-xamarin-forms/ ?

Comment: Do you know any test servers where I could test it? Namely I work on Xamarin.Auth and I doubt I'll have enough time to setup Keycloak server side for lab.

Comment: No response for long time. Can anyone direct me to the right link? I couldn't find Keycloak implementation for Xamarin forms.

Comment: @Shanthini Did you get a solution for Keycloak implementation in Xamarin forms?